# Getting negative voltage on resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Using superposition i first killed V2 and then calculated the parallel of R1 and R2 resulting in the following circuit:
[image]

Next using Ohm Law i found the current going through Ir3 = (4/2) = 2 and then the voltage of R3 V=2k(Ohm) * 2mA= 4V

Concluding, the voltage applied by V3 on R3 is 4V.
And i remembered Vo = Vab2 + 4 <=> -2 = Vab2 <=> Vab2 = -2 . 
Im stuck on this step because im getting a negative voltage and i dont know where it went wrong and i can't find the voltage of V2. 
I can't post the  image but next i killed V3.

Comment: "*Ir3 = (4/2) = 2*". Should that be \$ I_{R3} = \frac {V_3}{R1 + R2}= \frac {4}{1.2 + 2} \$?

Comment: @DwayneReid It is not negative.

Comment: Positive or negative depends on the reference point which hasn't been indicated on the schematics.

Comment: @Transistor i have to sum all resistances in series if i want the current of only 1?Is that what you mean? If it is , yes i have been doing it wrongly.

Comment: Yes. The voltage is applied across the sum of the resistances. The current must be calculated using the sum of the resistances.

Comment: @Transistor It hasnt been marked because i dont know how to use the reference point, being completly honest. Thanks for the formula correction!

Comment: You have a few options: use a ground symbol or the "node" component. Another tip: you don't need to take screenshots of the CircuitLab schematics. They embed directly in when you create them in the post. Then you can edit them or we can copy them into answers and edit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think you are wrong?

Calculating Vo with V2 shorted will get you a negative voltage \$-2.5V\$ ...

From \$ I*R2 = (V3 / (R1||R2 + R3) * R3 = (-4 / 3.2) * 2 = -2.5V\$

(Assuming the bottom line as your reference, which is traditional, and in keeping with the marked Vo.)

You can verify this in the simulator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3KI34.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That just means whatever \$V2\$ is, it needs to raise the output by \$4.5V\$.
Which should lead you nicely into the math of the second part of your superposition puzzle.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, i just assumed it was impossible for a voltage to be negative and i made some errors

Comment: @Alex.. any voltage is negative... it just depends where you measure it from.

Comment: @Alex, You should get comfortable with negative voltages. They're completely common and expected in analog circuits (and even some digital circuits). Just turn your meter around and all your positive voltages turn into negative ones and vice versa.